# change the color while clicking jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new to jquery =)

I want to achieve the effect of pressing on the touch devices.
mouseover only works on PC

how do I solve this problem?

Thank you!)

```js
$('.pleer-controls__right').click(function(){
  $(this).toggleClass('clicked');
});
```

I want the button not to stick after a click

https://jsfiddle.net/vvs10/pL14gfwa/15/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[UPDATE]

You can use the jquery mobile touch events. Simply add the following jquery into your code

```
$(".pleer-controls__right").on("tap",function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('clicked');
});
```

Read more about these events here - https://micropyramid.com/blog/how-to-use-jquery-mobile-touch-events/

Comment: this code works, but the button sticks on touch devices(

Comment: @R10 what do you mean by that?

Comment: when clicked, the button changes color and does not return to its original state after. it only works with a double click. I only want to make an effect when I press the button and remove it when I release it. this problem is for touch devices

Comment: Thank you! I wrote this code and it works for touch devices.                                                                                      
`document.querySelector('.pleer-controls__play').addEventListener("touchstart", myTouch);
document.querySelector('.pleer-controls__play').addEventListener("touchend", myTouchEnd);

function myTouch(){
  console.log('touch');
  $(this).toggleClass('clicked');
}

function myTouchEnd(){
  console.log('end');
  $(this).removeClass('clicked');
} `

Comment: @R10 Please do upvote or accept the answer if it helped you. Or add your answer and accept it for others to look for.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.addEventListener("touchstart", function() {}, true);
```

This snippet will enable hover effects for touchscreens.

Comment: how will it work in my code? https://jsfiddle.net/vvs10/pL14gfwa/11/